# Wireshark and wifi monitor mode failing

Tags: wifi, monitor, wireshark, sniffing

I want to sniff wifi packets with wireshark but monitor mode seems to fail. I'm using backtrack 5 and an alpha AWUS036H wifi usb card, i try to sniff my own box without encryption.

Here is what i'm doing to activate monitor mode :

> root@root:~# airmon-ng start wlan0

wich seems to be working :

> root@root:~# iwconfig mon0
>   mon0      IEEE 802.11bg  Mode:Monitor Tx-Power=20 dBm
>             Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:on

However when i start capturing on mon0 in wireshark i'm only getting broadcast packets.
In capture options the "capture packets in monitor mode" option is grayed out.

I do not understand what's going on. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

What channel number is your mon0 interface set to?

Comment: Aha @pslayer89 again (http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5826/cant-check-monitor-mode-checkbox-on-ubuntu?), thanks for your help. I will copy paste first part of my reply from Wireshark Q&A: My problem was that I was able to see broadcast data like beacons in monitor mode but I could not get any HTTP request. Tests where done with my smartphone connected to an open hotspot. The solution was to set WiFi channel to the hotspot one! I did iwconfig wlan0 channel 6 in my case and it worked. To capture data while surfing the internet I do airmon-ng start wlan0 otherwise net connection crashes.